# Size of button in header with text inside is different then size with icon inside. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

everything was said in my topic. Thank you. Link to my site: [site](http://testing3.ats-global.com/cz/cs/)

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="header" data-role="header" data-theme="a">
    <div class="ui-btn-right" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"> <a href="/{$country}/{$lang}/1_reseni-pro-prumyslovou-a-procesni-automatizaci-kvalitu-a-it.html" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>  <a id="menu" href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="grid" data-theme="b" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a>
 <a id="globe_menu" href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b"><img align="left" src="/css/globe_white.png"/></a>
 <a style="padding-bottom: 1px;" id="lang_menu" href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b"><b>EN</b></a>
 <a id="search_menu" href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="search" data-theme="b" data-iconpos="notext">Search</a>

    </div>
    <div id="center_logo" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 10px; width: 150px;">
        <img border="0" src="/images/logo_ats.png" alt="ATS Logo" />
    </div>
    <div style="min-height: 15px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: care to post a fiddle or screenshot? It seems quite reasonable that if you don't set the buttons dimensions it will take whatever it finds appropiate, but again seeing what you're trying to say would be helpful

Comment: updated with screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language button had padding in it's style, replace

```
<a style="padding-bottom: 1px;" id="lang_menu" href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b"><b>EN</b></a>
```

with this

```
 <a id="lang_menu" href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b"><b>EN</b></a>
```

(I removed the padding)

I checked on a fiddle and it gets it's correct height that way.

Comment: When i try on pc browser its ok but when i try on opera mobile emulator it is 2px smaller then other buttons in header. Do u know why ?

Comment: Try forcing it's size, setting style="height:20px" in your anchors